# What's the difference between /etc/cron.hourly and crontab -e?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

What's the difference between creating a script in

`/etc/cron.hourly/myScript`

Or adding the script in `crontab -e` with:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 * * * * myScript
```

When I run `crontab -l` or `sudo crontab -l` I don't see the scripts created in /etc/cron.*

Is there any advantage of using one or the other?

Comment: I think it is just per user schedule task(crontab -e) vs per system schedule task(/etc/cron.*).

Comment: Don't think @alfred fact ;-) If you have lots of scripts for lots of users /etc/crontab lets you add them all into 1 place. with crontab you'd need a crontab per user or set the script up to differentiate between users yourself.

Comment: @Rinzwind _add them all into 1 place_ That's a good advantage of using the system-wide crontab. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `crontab` files (the kind produced by non-`root` `crontab -e`) are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user>`. `root` `cron` jobs are run through `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and `/etc/cron.monthly`, and controlled via `/etc/crontab`. The comments at the top of `/etc/crontab` say:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```