# Ubuntu-Server: Reboot command in crontab. Trigger only if required

Tags: server, cron, reboot

Is there a way to setup a command in crontab so that every morning at, for example, 3am it checks to see if a restart is required, and if yes then call the reboot command?

Can I somehow make use of:

```
/var/run/reboot-required
```

---

**Edit:**

I've tried create a script as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
  reboot
fi
```

Then called that script in `sudo crontab -e` but it doesn't appear to be rebooting the machine. Instead, I can't open an SSH session to the server and I have to physically power-cycle the machine to actually reboot it and get shell access again.

---

**Edit 2:**

My script now looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
  /sbin/reboot
fi
```

I've called the script in `/etc/crontab` and the same problem as in my first edit persists.

---

**Edit 3: Working**

Once I changed the script to call:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
  /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

And still having it under `/etc/crontab`, the whole process works as I intended it to.

Now if a Restart Required message is present, the system reboots, otherwise it continues to trek on.

Comment: `cron` runs in a very limited environment - you should either set an appropriate `PATH` in your script, or at least use the absolute path for the reboot command (`/sbin/reboot`)

Comment: `root` `cron` jobs are not created through `crontab -e`, rather they are controlled through `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}`

Comment: @steeldriver : I modified my script to call `/sbin/reboot` instead. @waltinator : I'm confused. I've been adding all my cron jobs through `sudo crontab -e` and modifying the file that comes up. Are you saying that because this would be a root command, that I should call it under the locations you specified?

Comment: @JJT: See my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/828249/whats-the-difference-between-etc-cron-hourly-and-crontab-e/828287#828287